# ceiling and floor in TreeMap java

Tags: java, treemap, sortedlist, ceil

I found myself using a TreeMap simply because I needed the  capability of looking something up with the floorEntry() (and ceilingEntry()) methods. This obviously make the code a bit clumsy. So does anyone happen to know if there is any built-in sorted list that would offer the same functionality as floorEntry()?

So for instance, I have a `List<Integer> list`. and I have a value `int num`. I'd like to get the max  element in `list` that is not greater than `num`

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `TreeSet`, and its `floor` and `ceiling` methods, no?  Why use a `Map`?

Comment: I believe Louis is right though. That's the most straight-forward answer to your question.

Comment: Oh, I would use a map as the floor or value key (or data in a Set) is the entry for a dictionary record. e.g, color temperature, rgb value as the <Integer, Color> dictionary entry. dbm value -> Signal Strength <Double, String>. If you don't need a fast dictionary lookup based onlwm/hwm, than perhaps a map is not the correct choice for you.